# How does this turn into a number in the recursion ? Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, numbers, return

I am just reading a book and it mentioned about recursion but I am a bit confused.

I know what it's doing but just a part of it I don't understand how it's done.

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}

console.log(power(2, 3));
```

the `power(base, exponent - 1)` inside the else statement, how did this turn up into a number so that `base` can multiply it?

P.S. Sorry everyone, I just realized my title might be a bit different from what I wanted to ask even though an answer is given.  I just wasn't sure how this recursion works because I kept on wondering how can `base * power(base, exponent - 1)` because for the first loop it'll be something like `2* power(2, 3 - 1)` and `power(2, 3 - 1)` isn't a number.  How can the base multiply it but again the answer showed me visually that I just wasn't imagining it correctly to see.

Comment: What do you expect `power(base, exponent - 1)` to return? Especially consider the case where `exponent === 1`

Comment: `return 1;` <- that's how

Comment: @MattBurland I didn't know what to expect to return but with the demonstration nikhil provided I finally see it visually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `power(base, exponent - 1)` inside the else statement returns the result of the function which is a number.

Elaboration for `power(2, 3)`

This will return 2*(2*(2*(1))) = 8

```
2 * (power(2,2))
2 * (2 * (power(2,1)))
2 * (2 * (2 * (power(2,0))))
2 * (2 * (2 * (1)))
```

Comment: Ah!, thank you! this is the example I needed to see how the flow works! Thank you.  Thank you.